# Is there any way to set name of device node in Android?

Tags: android, linux

In general linux, udev rules file is present, which is read by udev daemon.
This file provides many facilities like identifying the device and changing name of device nodes, etc

But in Android, there is no such rules file and hence there is no facility to change name of device node like /dev/input/eventX.
(Although there is init.rc file which allows us to change permissions but not device node name)

So, is there any way to change name of device node in android ?

Thanks !